# How to create N number of columns programmatically using C# with WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need to create N columns in WPF DataGrid where each column's `header = "i" (i = 1..N)` and then to add items to each column. I got a problem when tried to implement it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    var col = new DataGridTextColumn();
    col.Header = i.ToString();
    col.Binding = new Binding(i.ToString());
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(col);
    dataGrid.Items.Add(new { i = "some txt" });
}
```

The problem may be at the line `dataGrid.Items.Add(new { i = "some txt" });` to which I don't know how to fix it. At this line of code IDE tells **i** is an anonymous type, **i** is a number and not a property.

How can I add items to a column in this case?

Comment: I can build your code (after adding `N` and `dataGrid`) in .NET 4.8 / VS 2019.  What are you using?

Comment: My code is built too in .NET 4.8 / VS 2017, but the result is not what I expect: each column is empty => dataGrid.Items.Add(new { i = "some txt" }) does not work correct. Right result: 1 row and N columns, and each cell contains text "some txt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding to index should have format: `[index]`. Also you should add items after you created columns:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    var col = new DataGridTextColumn
    {
        Header = i.ToString(),
        Binding = new Binding("[" + i + "]"),
        IsReadOnly = true,
        Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star)
    };

    dataGrid.Columns.Add(col);
}

var rowData = Enumerable.Range(0, N).ToList();
dataGrid.Items.Add(rowData);
```

[image: dg]

Comment: I tried all ways given here but your answer helped me a lot. Can you explain, please, why is it more correct to bind to index in such a format: [index]?

Comment: @Eugene, it is how property path is implemented: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/propertypath-xaml-syntax?view=netframework-4.8#single-indexer-on-the-immediate-object-as-data-context, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.path?view=netframework-4.8#remarks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DataTable and add your columns to the DataTable. Then set that DataTable as the data source of your data grid view.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++){
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    for(int c = 0; c < numberOfColumns; c++){
        row[c] = "Your data here"       
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}

 MyDataGrid1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score -1):

Although I was able to build your demo similarly (using VS2017), I don't see it as practical as it does not show anything as no binding source of a specific type you are trying to set your binding context to.

Instead, here is something you might find useful.  If you have a collection (List, ObservableCollection, etc.) that you are querying or otherwise populating, and you want that to automatically build, you can do with reflection.  So example, I have a custom class

```
public class MySamplePerson
{
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   public string LastName {get; set;}
   public int Age {get; set;}
}
```

Then, in your method you prepare a list of these things

```
private void PrepareYourGrid()
{
   // build a sample list of the data and I'm populating with 3 entries
   var SampleData = new List<MySamplePerson>();
   SampleData.Add(new MySamplePerson{ FirstName = "Bill", LastName = "Board", Age = 62});
   SampleData.Add(new MySamplePerson{ FirstName = "Eileen", LastName = "Dover", Age = 32 });
   SampleData.Add(new MySamplePerson{ FirstName = "Ben", LastName = "Dover", Age = 33});


   // using reflection, I am taking the first instance within the list,
   // getting the type, and then getting a list of all the properties on that class.
   var pi = SampleData[0].GetType().GetProperties();
   // Now, for each property, go through and create a column
   foreach( var onePI in pi)
   {
      var col = new DataGridTextColumn();
      // header based on the property name and binding to that same column name,
      // not just some fixed "text" value you prove
      col.Header = onePI.Name;
      col.Binding = new Binding(onePI.Name);
      // now add the column to the grid
      MyDataGrid1.Columns.Add(col);
   }

   // Now I can set the ItemsSource for the grid to the list of records I created   
   MyDataGrid1.ItemsSource = SampleData;
}
```

In my sample, my form data grid was named "MyDataGrid1".  Now if you run, the grid will show as many rows as you have and each of the public properties exposed too..